# Cannot find module 'next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/routing-items.js'

Tags: npm, next.js

I just run an `npm upgrade` on my project tp update some dependencies, and now `npm run dev` will crash with this error message and the server will not start. I'm lost, how should I fix this?

Full dump:

```
Require stack:
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/.next/server/pages/_app.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/store.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/index.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:183:28)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object../utils/routing-items (/Users/guillermo/my-project/.next/server/pages/_app.js:693:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/guillermo/my-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:29:21)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js (/Users/guillermo/my-project/.next/server/pages/_app.js:398:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/guillermo/my-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/.next/server/pages/_app.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/store.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/index.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js',
    '/Users/guillermo/my-project/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
  ]
}

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Comment: Thanks Time Machine! I was able to restore the `routing-items.js` file from a Time Machine backup of the `node_modules` folder and everything seems to be running fine now. Weird.

Comment: What is your next.js version? Are you using custom config `next.config.js` ? I'm with version 12.1.6, and custom config can't resolve `../shared/lib/utils` inside `_app.js`. Pretty sure this have to do with those upgrade versions of Next12 and Webpack5.

Comment: I found out with Webpack5, you have to convert externals in config differently than for webpack4. So in NextJS `next.config.js`, the guide for config has been updated for webpack5: https://github.com/MoOx/moox.io/blob/db88a119c43deafab15afa2d11deac4b43700238/next.config.js#L7-L9

Comment: Yeah I'm using Next v12 and have a few edits to my `next.config.js`. I haven't updated since I fixed the problem by restoring the missing file.